# setSingleChoiceItems of ParcelableArray (Kotlin)

Tags: arrays, kotlin, android-alertdialog, bundle, parcelable

```
have a code: 
  
 val booksForDelete = arguments?.getParcelableArray("books")

  val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        val checkedItem = -1

        builder.setTitle("Choose the book for DELETE")
        
            .setSingleChoiceItems(booksForDelete?.**map**(Book::title)?.toTypedArray(),checkedItem){dialog, which ->
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Choosen book: ${booksForDelete?.map { Book::title}?.get(which)}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

in the line ".setSingleChoiceItems..." a have a mistake - "map" marked. What's wrong?

P.S.

```
data class Book(val title: String, val id: Int) : Parcelable {
constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
        source.readString()!!,
        source.readInt()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `booksForDelete?.map(Book::title)?.toTypedArray()` is syntactically correct.
However usually it's written in a more 'kotlin'-ic form:

```
booksForDelete?.map { it.title }?.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: @Дмитрий Unfortunately, you don't provide any additional info regarding the error: what kind of error, what you expect to get and what you actually get and so on and so forth.

I guess you're using an IDE like Intellij Idea: what does it say on the line?

Comment: thanks for answer. i take two arrays and solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try to cast your `Parcelable` array to `Array<Book>`:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") 
val booksForDelete = arguments?.getParcelableArray("books") as? Array<Book>
```